# Exe extractor windows 7 file recovery

Tags: windows-7

I recently created an .exe file on my pc and i would like to extract it to get all the files from it. I forgot to save it before i build it. Is it possible to extract it and get all of my files back?

Comment: So i can than build it again and save it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "extract it". Do you mean you want to get the original source code back? The original source code is not saved in the EXE.

Comment: So i cannot get the files and rebuild it?

Comment: Please be more specific what you mean by "the files". If you mean the source code, then no, you cannot recover the source code from the EXE. (Imagine if you could. You could take PHOTOSHOP.EXE, then apply the technique, and BOOM you have the source code to Photoshop.)

Comment: Ok thanks answer question with that

Comment: You didn't say what language your program is written in. If the language is interpreted, the source may be in there somewhere.